# How to use ffmpeg to extract live stream into a sequence of mp4

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to record a live stream to a sequence of mp4 on disk.  I'm able to do one file like this:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://source.com/live/stream -r 5 -t 60 c:\test.mp4
```

This results in one 60s mp4 (test.mp4). What I would like is something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://source.com/live/stream -r 5 -t 60 c:\test%d.mp4
```

That results in one 60s mp4 per minute (test1.mp4, test2.mp4, etc)  I'm finding plenty of examples for extracting single frames in a similar way, but not video.

I realize I can just loop a call to the first example, but I was hoping there would be a good way to do it with minimal loss between each file by letting ffmpeg handle the sequencing.  What is the cleanest way to record a live stream into a sequence of mp4?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [segment muxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment). Example command:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://source.com/live/stream -c copy -flags +global_header -f segment -segment_time 60 -segment_format_options movflags=+faststart -reset_timestamps 1 test%d.mp4
```

Comment: That is it exactly and you are amazing.  Thanks!

Comment: FYI - I found I needed to add -reset_timestamps 1  or the segments after the first one would not play correctly in most browsers.  See this explanation: http://www.dahuatu.com/JVwakkLZyM.html